# Configure and build libunwind for a mips target

Tags: mips, stack-unwinding

Does anyone know how to configure and build libunwind for a mips target (which is not the host on which the library is being built)?

Answer (score -1):

[It's officially supported](http://savannah.nongnu.org/forum/forum.php?forum_id=5772), just look at the docs or write to their own mailing list.

Comment: That is very gracious of you, but I already looked up the docs. They are simply not clear. That's exactly why I am posting my question here.